# Rollup configuration for filename hashes with a single input and output file

Tags: javascript, rollupjs

Say that I have this basic `rollup.config.js` file.

```
export default {
    input: 'src/main.js',
    output: {
        format: 'iife',
        file: 'dist/bundle.js',
    }
};
```

**I want the output file to have its hash in the file name** (e.g. `bundle-9f02a82b.js`). From what I can tell from the docs, the correct way to do this is with `options.entryFileNames`. However, that setting doesn’t seem to have any effect when outputting to `options.file`.

I have seen some people online mention that you can use `[hash]` in `output.file`, but that doesn’t seem to actually work.

```
export default {
    input: 'src/main.js',
    output: {
        format: 'iife',
        file: 'dist/bundle-[hash].js', // this doesn’t work
    },
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to get a hashed file name, you will have to replace `output.file` with `output.dir` and `output.entryFileNames`.

In your example that would be:

```js
export default {
    input: 'src/main.js',
    output: {
        format: 'iife',
        dir: 'build',
        entryFileNames: 'bundle-[hash].js',
    },
};
```